# How to check if a given subset is a subspace?

Tags: matrices

Given
$$ V = \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$$

$$V_1 = \left\{A \in V: 
A \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} -
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}A =
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

$$V_2 = \left\{A \in V: 
A \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} -
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}A =
 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

I've been given these subsets of $V$ and I need to check if they are subspaces of $V.$

I'm aware of the rules of whether a subset is a subspace,

If it contains the zero vector,
if $V$ contains a vector $v$ multiplied by a scalar
and if $V$ contains the combination of $2$ vectors from within $V.$

I'm not sure what to do about this issue, specifically on how to manipulate the argument I have inside the $V1/V2$ brackets in order to give me the information I need.

Any tips will be happily accepted
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the argument with the zero matrix, can you argue why $V_1$ isn't a subspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to recap, if $V$ is a (real) vector space, then $U\subseteq V$ is a vector subspace of $V$ if

- $0\in U$
- $v+\lambda w\in U$ whenever $v$ and $w$ belong to $U$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb R$.

You can easily prove that the zero-matrix does not belong to $V_1$, hence $V_1$ cannot be a vector subspace.

Secondly, you can show that both of above conditions hold for $V_2$:

- $0\in V$ belongs to $V_2$, as it satisfies the given equation.
- Take $A,B\in V_2$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb R$. As $A,B$ belong to $V_2$, they satisfy the corresponding equation. Now, just check that $(A+\lambda B)$ also satisfies the equation. It is a direct computation, no fancy tricks involved.